# Calculating club membership data (new, past and current) during a period

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with data for club memberships.

Here the aim is, for a period between two dates, to calculate the following, in MySQL:

- the number of new members during the period.
- the number of members who cancelled during the period
- the number of members who re-joined during the period

For example, suppose we have the following membership data:

```
msid  id  start                 cancelled
1     1   2020-01-01 09:00:00   null
2     2   2020-01-01 09:00:00   2020-12-31 09:00:00
3     2   2021-01-01 09:00:00   null
4     3   2020-01-01 09:00:00   2020-06-30 09:00:00
5     3   2020-02-01 09:00:00   2020-06-30 09:00:00
6     3   2020-07-01 09:00:00   null
```

where `msid` is the primary key for this table, and `id` is the member ID.

For the following selection of periods we should return the following:

```
period_start         period_end           new  cancelled  rejoined
2020-01-01 00:00:00  2020-01-01 23:59:59  3    0          0
2020-01-01 00:00:00  2020-06-30 23:59:59  3    1          0
2020-01-01 00:00:00  2020-07-01 23:59:59  3    1          1
2020-01-01 00:00:00  2020-12-31 23:59:59  3    2          1
2020-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 23:59:59  3    2          2
2020-07-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 23:59:59  0    1          2
2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-01 23:59:59  0    0          1
```

It is possible for a member to have multiple current memberships, as in the case of ID 3, but they should only be counted once when they cancel.

[Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=857482064d94692aaf69cb5157daa7c4) with the membership data in table `dt` and the time periods in table `periods`

Comment: Where do the periods come from?  They have nothing to do with the original data, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is correct, they are unrelated. The actual data consist of around 600,000 membership records for a chain of gyms. It is required to report the 3 totals mentioned over any period. For instance it might be daily for the current month, It could be Monthly over 2 years, it could be yearly over a few years, or it could be just an single arbitrary period that management wishes to see these data for. I simply created those periods to coincide with some of the dates in the toy data in order that the correctness of the query can be checked.

Comment: Your column names are confusing.  Does `cm-pm` mean cancelled?  Does `pm-cm` mean rejoined?  I think the numbers for 2020-01-01 to 2021-01-23:59:59 are incorrect, or perhaps I don't understand the required logic.  With 3 members, I'd say for that date range you had 3 new (1,2,3), 0 cancelled (because they are all still members, and 0 rejoined (because they are all still members, although some cancelled and rejoined within the chosen date range).  Regardless, the query logic is possible -- but I'd rather be sure I'm answering the right question.

Comment: @dougp Sorry, I have not explained this well. I have edited the question and changed the names. Regarding the period mentioned,  2020-01-01 to 2021-01-23:59:59, yes there were 3 new members who joined. 2 of these cancelled during the period, and both of these also re-joined during the period, hence it is 2 and 2.

Comment: In this line: `5     3   2020-02-01 09:00:00   2020-06-30 09:00:00`  member with id = 3 has a new membership. Shouldn't rejoined be 1 for 2020-01-01 00:00:00 to 2020-06-30 23:59:59?

Comment: for last two periods why new memberships are 0 ?

Comment: @forpas Thanks, but no, in this case they were already a current member. Maybe I should make the definition of re-joining more explicit ? TBH I find this data surprisingly difficult to work with !

Comment: @eshirvana that is because a "new" membership is the *first* membership for any member.  Any subsequent membership is either a re-join (if they have cancelled their existing membership, or an additional membership if they are already a current member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am still learning myself, I am not sure this is the minimal solution, but it does the job.

1. As I understand, you define a member as being *new* when they start their first membership (rather than when starting *a second* new membership, or member `3` would have counted as *new* twice). That means that selecting the minimum start date for each member gives you the corresponding dates.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT id, MIN(start) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS start FROM dt
   ```
2. Cancellation dates are pretty straightforward, they are basically the non `NULL` entries in the respective column.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT id, cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL
   ```
3. From your example, I gather that re-joining dates should be start dates that occur after a previous cancellation. Therefore, we can re-use the second query above to get them. I select `DISTINCT` to make sure that each date is only listed once for each user (if e.g. a member cancels and re-joins multiple times)

   ```
   WITH
       tab_cancelled as (SELECT DISTINCT id, cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL)
   SELECT DISTINCT dt.id, dt.start as rejoined 
              FROM dt 
        INNER JOIN tab_cancelled tc
                ON tc.id = dt.id 
               AND dt.start > tc.cancelled
   ```

To put it all together, I first used nested `LEFT JOINS` that check whether the respective dates lie within each period and use `COUNT() OVER PARTITION` to get the amounts for each period:

```
WITH 
  tab_start as (SELECT DISTINCT id, min(start) over (partition by id) as start FROM dt),
  tab_cancelled as (SELECT DISTINCT id, cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL),
  tab_rejoined as (SELECT DISTINCT dt.id, dt.start as rejoined FROM dt INNER JOIN tab_cancelled tc ON tc.id = dt.id AND dt.start > tc.cancelled)
SELECT DISTINCT period_start,
                period_end,
                new,
                cancelled,
                COUNT(dt3.id) over (partition by period_start, period_end) as rejoined
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT period_start, 
                        period_end, 
                        new,
                        COUNT(dt2.id) over (partition by period_start, period_end) as cancelled
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT period_start,
                                period_end, 
                                COUNT(dt1.id) over (partition by period_start, period_end) as new
                  FROM periods
             LEFT JOIN tab_start as dt1
                    ON dt1.start between period_start and period_end) u
     LEFT JOIN tab_cancelled as dt2
            ON dt2.cancelled between period_start and period_end) v
LEFT JOIN tab_rejoined as dt3
       ON dt3.rejoined between period_start and period_end
```

Alternatively, the same can be achieved without window functions using `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` and `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH 
  tab_start as (SELECT DISTINCT id, min(start) over (partition by id) as start FROM dt),
  tab_cancelled as (SELECT DISTINCT id, cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL),
  tab_rejoined as (SELECT DISTINCT dt.id, dt.start as rejoined FROM dt INNER JOIN tab_cancelled tc ON tc.id = dt.id AND dt.start > tc.cancelled)
SELECT DISTINCT period_start, 
                period_end, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt1.id) as new,
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt2.id, dt2.cancelled) as cancelled,
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt3.id, dt3.rejoined) as rejoined
     FROM periods
LEFT JOIN tab_start as dt1
       ON dt1.start between period_start and period_end
LEFT JOIN tab_cancelled as dt2
       ON dt2.cancelled between period_start and period_end
LEFT JOIN tab_rejoined as dt3
       ON dt3.rejoined between period_start and period_end
GROUP BY period_start, period_end
```

Either way, this should give you the desired result:

| period_start | period_end | new | cancelled | rejoined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 23:59:59 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-06-30 23:59:59 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-07-01 23:59:59 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-12-31 23:59:59 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:59:59 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:59:59 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:59:59 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Note that both of this this will (by design) count multiple cancellations for a single user with multiple memberships individually if they should occur on different dates. The same is true if the same user quits and joins multiple times within a period. If you don't want both of this to happen, you can `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` within each period, i.e. count distinct ids rather than datetime-id-combinations.

```
WITH 
  tab_start as (SELECT DISTINCT id, min(start) over (partition by id) as start FROM dt),
  tab_cancelled as (SELECT DISTINCT id, cancelled FROM dt WHERE cancelled IS NOT NULL),
  tab_rejoined as (SELECT DISTINCT dt.id, dt.start as rejoined FROM dt INNER JOIN tab_cancelled tc ON tc.id = dt.id AND dt.start > tc.cancelled)
SELECT DISTINCT period_start, 
                period_end, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt1.id) as new,
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt2.id) as cancelled,
                COUNT(DISTINCT dt3.id) as rejoined
     FROM periods
LEFT JOIN tab_start as dt1
       ON dt1.start between period_start and period_end
LEFT JOIN tab_cancelled as dt2
       ON dt2.cancelled between period_start and period_end
LEFT JOIN tab_rejoined as dt3
       ON dt3.rejoined between period_start and period_end
GROUP BY period_start, period_end
```

For your sample data, the result is the same, so you have to take a look at your edge cases and decide how you want them to be counted.

As I wrote, maybe this can be condensed somehow or improved performance-wise, but this is what I can do.

You can find an according *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=669b7b4c98614d670c30486fb7f4a434).

Comment: Thank you (+1) this looks extremely promising ! I will study it and test it :)

Comment: This turned out to be excellent, thanks !

Comment: Hi, this code has been extremely useful. Thanks again. On real data the first method is significantly faster than the 2nd (10-20 secs vs 2-3 hours), but it turns out that I need to make the adjustment you pointed out in the case of multiple cancellations (ie use `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` instead of the id-time combinations. While this works great for the 2nd method, I can't figure out how to make it work for the first. I wondered if you can help ? I'd be happy to ask a new question, and ping you here, if you'd like ?

Comment: @JoeKing `DISTINCT` is not possible in window functions in MySql, but it can be done with a little workaround. Too long for a comment though. Go ahead and ask another question, and I'll post it as an answer. BTW, I'd always encourage you to ask a new question for a new problem, since there are a lot of SQL gurus around here and one of them (or anyone else for that matter) might be able to contribute something even better...

Comment: Will do. Thank you ! I'll ping you on here when I've posted it !